Why is my speaker's output sound... like if it were being sent for headphones / headsets?
My setup is like this:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.
Linux kernel: 6.8.0-45 (it happened with other kernels as well).
I also have a Windows 11 system in the same computer and everything works well there, but fails in my Ubuntu. This rules out strictly hardware-related issues.

Other details:
Manufacturer:      ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Product Name:      ROG Zephyrus M16 GU604VI_GU604VI
Product Version:   1.0
Firmware Version:  GU604VI.312
System SKU:
Board Vendor:      ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Board Name:        GU604VI
Full ALSA details can be found here.
And the problem is:

Just to start, again: Everything works well in Windows. I have no problem there.
When I boot Ubuntu (the only other OS in my computer) and use it regularly, I can hear sound... but it sounds as if it were intended for the headphones instead (less intensity, somewhat metallic, ...the same you'd hear if your headphones were out of your ears, but close to you, and plugged to your computer).
When I use my headphones, both in Windows and Ubuntu, everything works well and the same.

So the only problem is: In Ubuntu (Tried 23.10 and 24.04), and related to the regular speakers, I hear the headphone-like sound when I play any sound, video, or live stream.
What can I do to fix my sound settings? I want to hear the by-speakers sound in the way it should be.
